# Racket - Find lists that has the same element in a 2D list

Tags: racket

Can someone please show me how to do this problem/give me a template? I'm not allowed to use map or lambda or any other advanced built-in functions, only list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First extract the country associated with the input string:

```
(define (get-country l s)
  (cond [(empty? (rest l)) (second (second (first l)))]
        [else (if (equal? s (first (first l)))
                  (second (second (first l)))
                  (get-country (rest l) s))]))
```

Then extract all strings that have that country associated with it:

```
(define (get-countries l s)
  (cond [(empty? l) '()]
        [else (if (equal? s (second (second (first l))))
                  (cons (first (first l)) (get-countries (rest l) s))
                  (get-countries (rest l) s))]))
```

Then put them together:

```
(define (same-country l s)
  (get-countries l (get-country l s)))
```

When we evaluate we get a result different from `(list "YUL" "YVR" "YWG" "YYZ")`:

```
> (same-country alist "YUL")
(list "YYZ" "YWG" "YUL" "YVR")
```

So we check if the result is a permutation of the desired list. First we make `is-permutation`:

```
(define (is-permutation l1 l2)
  (and (not (and (cons? l1) (empty? l2)))
       (not (and (empty? l1) (cons? l2)))
       (or (and (empty? l1) (empty? l2))
           (and (is-member (first l1) l2)
                (is-permutation (rest l1)
                                (remove-one (first l1) l2))))))

(define (is-member e l)
  (and (not (empty? l))
       (or (equal? (first l) e)
           (is-member e (rest l)))))

(define (remove-one e nel)
  (cond [(empty? (rest nel)) '()]
        [else (if (equal? (first nel) e)
                  (rest nel)
                  (cons (first nel) (remove-one e (rest nel))))]))
```

Then we can test:

```
> (is-permutation (same-country alist "YUL")
                  (list "YUL" "YVR" "YWG" "YYZ"))
#true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although I want to ask how to build my own sort function that produces a new list with all the strings arranged in ascending order? <3

Comment: Unrelated to the top level question, but what you're looking for is similar to https://htdp.org/2019-02-24/part_two.html#%28counter._%28figure._fig~3asort%29%29

except instead of using `>=` in `insert` to order numbers in descending order, you use `string<?` to order strings in ascending order